# loop through all elements (dynamically driven content) if they all still have a custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic, yui

On this post [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691630/loop-through-all-elements-dynamically-driven-content-if-they-all-still-have-sp) I asked this question also.

I have the following markup:

```
 <ul id="tracks"> 
 <li pl_id="14" class="item" id="5" >1</li> 
 <li class="item" id="1" >2</li>
 <li pl_id="14" class="item" id="3" >3</li>
 </ul>
```

If all the li's have the pl_id attr then show a button.
In the above case the button should be hidden...

As an answer I got the following:

```
$("#buttonID").toggle($("ul > li").filter(function() {
return !this.hasAttribute("pl_id");
}).length === 0);
```

with a demo: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HBbk3/)

However - 
This is not working with <strike>live ajax</strike> dynamically driven content (and dragging and dropping of the li's with yui3.
the li can be added and removed at all times
So, how can I make this a 'live' event?
I want to add to that, that I would like to extend it to having the same value as well
so: all having pl_id=1 is ok
one of those havinf pl_id=2 is: hide button.

**Here my new demo:**
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/double0seven/HBbk3/4/)

Comment: Please post the AJAX request code you have. Also FYI, most of the attributes you have specified are invalid - which may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: It looks like you're using custom attributes, which are likely invalid HTML (not that that makes much of a difference). You should probably be using [`[data-*]`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) attributes.

Comment: ok forget all the custom attributes, they work for me.
I will amend the code to only keep the one for this example.

Comment: look at the demo I posted on the bottom of my post

Answer (score 0):

When you say ajax content, are you making sure that your code runs onSucess() of ajax call? Make sure that happens and your code would be fine.

There is no ajax request in the example you have provided. So I assume that is the problem